chmod responds cannot access
A command
chmod -R 775 /home/den/backup/*.sh  

responds with
No such file or directory  

I know there are shells within that structure, specifically some at /home/den/backup/shells
What is wrong with my command?

You can not use -R with *.sh. Your directories are NOT in
chmod -R 775 /home/den/backup/*.sh

If you want *.sh inside /home/den/backup/shells it needs to be
chmod 775 /home/den/backup/*/*.sh

A method to do it recursive for all files ending in .sh:
find /home/den/backup/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;


close enough - thanks.  I've go with find /home/den/backup -name "*.sh" -exec chmod 775 {} ;

Just a performance note ... find /home/den/backup/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} + (using + instead of \;) would allow passing as much as possible multiple filenames at once as arguments to chmod which can handle multiple file arguments .. This should greatly improve performance ... while with \;, chmod is invoked for each single file separately.

And users of zsh can use /home/den/backup/**/*.sh instead of the find command. Maybe bash has similar functionality, not sure.
